# How can I see trees for the forest?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc-3, refactoring, resharper

Resharper finds 1,953 issues with a virginal asp.net MVC 3 Internet app (I didn't even touch the code - only looked at it):

```
Common Practices and Code Improvements: 1024 issues
Constraints Violations: 150 issues
Potential Code Quality Issues: 252
Redundancies in Code: 77 issues
Redundancies in Symbol Declarations: 450 issues
```

How is an asp.net newbie to know (when he tries to resharpen his own code) which issues are truly issues and which are really non-issues?

Comment: Is this a real question?

Comment: Newbies are not expected to be able to distinguish.  That comes with experience.

Comment: Resharper highlights these same issues in the code editor itself as you type the code, or even after that

Comment: They're all real issues. If they weren't, they wouldn't need looking into, and Resharper wouldn't be finding issue with them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All of those errors except for 5 are from the included js.  Do you really need to be checking for code issues in Microsoft.Ajax.js?

The 5 issues found in .cs are for very common unused usings: System, System.Linq, System.Collections.Generic etc.

I hope this isn't the biggest issue you address today.

Comment: Anything to do with programming would NEVER be the biggest issue I face any day.